Field ratingRepository in service.impl.RatingServiceImpl required a bean of type 'repository.RatingRepository' that could not be found
RatingServiceApplication
    package com.catto.RatingService;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan({"controller", "service", "repository"})
    public class RatingServiceApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(RatingServiceApplication.class, args);
        }
    }

RatingRepository

import model.Rating;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface RatingRepository extends MongoRepository<Rating, String> {
    List<Rating> findByUserId(Long userId);

    List<Rating> findByHotelId(Long hotelId);
}

CASE 1: If the project structure is this package-structure then I get following error
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field ratingRepository in service.impl.RatingServiceImpl required a bean of type 'repository.RatingRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'repository.RatingRepository' in your configuration.

CASE 2: If the project structure is this package-structure then I don't get any error and the application works as expected.
I have added ComponentScan and it creates beans for other files(i.e. service, controller) which is at the same level as repository.
Please let me know how to resolve the issue in CASE 1. Thanks.
